# Dropdown menu lebal search filter

Tags: javascript, html, label, blogger

I would just like to ask some help regarding my blog. How do I connect the two drop down list boxes of `labels`. To explain it further what I wanted to do is, I chose a category on the first drop down list box of label, for example I chose "love" it will show all the posts that has a label of love and when I choose a category from the second drop down list box of `label` of countries for example Canada it will show all the labels of love with a label of Canada in it. What happens when I choose a label from the second drop down list box it resets the first drop down from scratch meaning it all shows the posts which has a label of Canada in it without considering the first label that I chose from the first drop down list box.

I HAVE FOUND THIS.. [Working example](http://pootih.blogspot.in)

How I can do same on my blog?

```
<b:section class='sectopbar' id='sectopbar' showaddelement='yes'>
    <b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='Labels' type='Label'>
        <b:includable id='main'>
            <b:if cond='data:title'>
                <h2 />
            </b:if>
            <div class='widget-   content'>
                <br />
                <select onchange='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
                    <option>Select a   Category</option>
                    <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
                        <option expr:value='data:label.url'>
                            <data:label.name /> (<data:label.count />)
                        </option>
                    </b:loop>
                </select>
                <b:include name='quickedit' />
            </div>
        </b:includable>
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
<div>
    <b:section class='sectopbar2' id='sectopbar2' showaddelement='yes'>
        <b:widget id='Label2' locked='false' title='Labels' type='Label'>
            <b:includable id='main'>
                <b:if cond='data:title'>
                    <h2 />
                </b:if>
                <div class='widget- content'>
                    <br />
                    <select onchange='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
                        <option>Select a Country</option>
                        <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
                            <option expr:value='data:label.url'>
                                <data:label.name /> (<data:label.count />)
                            </option>
                        </b:loop>
                    </select>
                    <b:include name='quickedit' />
                </div>
            </b:includable>
        </b:widget>
    </b:section
```

Comment: Even though you are have JavaScript marked on your tags, it sounds like you might be using an aspx postback to control your page load.  If that is the case, just do a `Page.IsPostBack` on the `C#` event handler for your drop down and modify your code appropriately.  However, if this is an issue in JavaScript, this comment will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just Solved

**Add new widget in blog and paste this script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="tabs-outer">
    <div class="tabs-cap-top cap-top">
        <div class="cap-left"></div>
        <div class="cap-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left">
        <div class="fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right"></div>
        <div class="region-inner tabs-inner">
            <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol">
                <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML3">
                    <h2 class="title">Multi Label Search</h2>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <div id="multi-search">
                            <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
                                <option value="">Columns</option>
                                <option value="1%20Column+">1 Column</option>
                                <option value="2%20Column+">2 Column</option>
                                <option value="3%20Column+">3 Column</option>
                                <option value="4%20Column+">4 Column</option>
                            </select>
                            <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
                                <option value="">Sidebars</option>
                                <option value="1%20Left%20Sidebar+">1 Left Sidebar</option>
                                <option value="2%20Left%20Sidebar+">2 Left Sidebar</option>
                                <option value="1%20Right%20Sidebar+">1 Right Sidebar</option>
                                <option value="2%20Right%20Sidebar+">2 Right Sidebar</option>
                                <option value="Left%20and%20Right+">Left and Right</option>
                            </select>
                            <select id="cmbColor" name="cmbColor">
                                <option value="">Colors</option>
                                <option value="Black+">Black</option>
                                <option value="Blue+">Blue</option>
                                <option value="Brown+">Brown</option>
                                <option value="Green+">Green</option>
                                <option value="Gray+">Gray</option>
                                <option value="Orange+">Orange</option>
                                <option value="Pink+">Pink</option>
                                <option value="Red+">Red</option>
                                <option value="Violet+">Violet</option>
                                <option value="White+">White</option>
                                <option value="Yellow+">Yellow</option>
                            </select>
                            <select id="cmbFeatures" name="cmbFeatures">
                                <option value="">Features</option>
                                <option value="Ads%20Ready">Ads Ready</option>
                                <option value="Bookmark%20Ready">Bookmark Ready</option>
                                <option value="Custom%20Navbar">Custom Navbar</option>
                                <option value="Page%20Number">Page Number</option>
                                <option value="Slideshow">Slideshow</option>
                            </select>
                            <input onclick=" getValue() " value="Filter" type="button">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <span class="widget-item-control">
                            <span class="item-control blog-admin">
                                <a class="quickedit" href="//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4472703516037708465&amp;widgetType=HTML&amp;widgetId=HTML3&amp;action=editWidget&amp;sectionId=crosscol" onclick=" return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML3&quot;)); " target="configHTML3" title="Edit">
                                    <img alt="" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" height="18" width="18">
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol-overflow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
        <div class="cap-left"></div>
        <div class="cap-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
        var valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value;
        valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;
        valcmbColor = document.getElementById("cmbColor").value;
        valcmbFeatures = document.getElementById("cmbFeatures").value;
        valOutput = (valcmbColumn + valcmbSidebar + valcmbColor + valcmbFeatures);
        window.open("/search/label/" + valOutput, "_self");
    }

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == "block") {
            e.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            e.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```