# Links redirecting to wrong page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

This is my [Blog](http://testpostvijay.blogspot.in/)

I have added multi label search in the homepage.

but when i select green and gray tags from the menu and after clicking the filter it is redirecting to example.com/search/?q=label:blue|label:black 
page

But want to redirect tags green and gray to label:green|label:gray

The below is the code

```html
<!doctype html>


<div class="tabs-outer">
  <div class="tabs-cap-top cap-top">
    <div class="cap-left"></div>
    <div class="cap-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left">
    <div class="fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right"></div>
    <div class="region-inner tabs-inner">
      <div class="tabs section" id="main">
        <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML3">
          <h2 class="title">Multi Label Search</h2>
          <div class="widget-content">
            <div id="multi-search">
              <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
                <option value="" />Columns
                <option value="green+" />green
                <option value="blue+" />blue
              </select>
              <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
                <option value="" />Sidebars
                <option value="Gray+" />Gray
                <option value="black+" />black

              </select>

              <input onclick=" getValue() " value="Filter" type="button" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <span class="widget-item-control">
                                <span class="item-control blog-admin">
                                    <a class="quickedit" href="https://www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=5988384389032442595&action=editWidget&sectionId=main" onclick=" return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML3&quot;)); " target="configHTML3" title="Edit">
                                        <img alt="" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" height="18" width="18" />
                                    </a>
                                </span>
          </span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs section" id="main"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
    <div class="cap-left"></div>
    <div class="cap-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getValue() {
    var
      valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value = "green";
    valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value = "|label:Gray";

    valOutput = (valcmbColumn + valcmbSidebar);
    window.open("/search/?q=label:" + valOutput, "_self");

    valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value = "blue";
    valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value = "|label:black";

    valOutput = (valcmbColumn + valcmbSidebar);
    window.open("/search/?q=label:" + valOutput, "_self");


  }




  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == "block") {
      e.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      e.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>


</!doctype>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value="blue";` Are you sure you want to assign a value to that element here?

Comment: Here is the example iam working on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406754/dropdown-menu-lebal-search-filter

Comment: That's nice but that doesn't help. It looks like you're assigning a value to an input when you shouldn't be.

Comment: Mike is right your getValue function looks fishy. I wonder Why you are assigning value in such a way? Anyways remember that it will be last occurring statement who's value is actually retained

Comment: But is there any way to do it i have seen in w3schools to assign that value="blue" at document.getelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think this should solve the problem. I am not able to test it with the code you have provided

```
   function getValue() {
     var valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value;
     var valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;

    valOutput = "label:"+valcmbColumn+"|label:"+ valcmbSidebar;
    window.open("/search/?q=" + valOutput, "_self");
  }
```

Let me know if it is working or not

Comment: it work like a legend but small problem dude it work with all tags which i want to include more tags in future?

Comment: Yeah off course it will because it retrieves the value from you select box directly. I think you must take a basic course of javascript & jquery at codecademy it will help you a lot.

Comment: thanks yeah i should learn more things thanks once again @geeksal it would helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    
    
    <div class="tabs-outer">
        <div class="tabs-cap-top cap-top">
            <div class="cap-left"></div>
            <div class="cap-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left">
            <div class="fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right"></div>
            <div class="region-inner tabs-inner">
                <div class="tabs section" id="main">
                    <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML3">
                        <h2 class="title">Multi Label Search</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <div id="multi-search">
                                <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
                                    <option value="" />Columns
                                    <option value="green" />green
                                    <option value="blue" />blue
                                </select>
                                <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
                                    <option value="" />Sidebars
                                    <option value="gray" />Gray
                                    <option value="black" />black
                                    
                                </select>
                                
                                <input onclick=" getValue() " value="Filter" type="button" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <span class="widget-item-control">
                                <span class="item-control blog-admin">
                                    <a class="quickedit" href="https://www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=5988384389032442595&action=editWidget&sectionId=main" onclick=" return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML3&quot;)); " target="configHTML3" title="Edit">
                                        <img alt="" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" height="18" width="18" />
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabs section" id="main"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
            <div class="cap-left"></div>
            <div class="cap-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getValue() {
            valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value;
            valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;          
            valOutput = (valcmbColumn +"|"+ valcmbSidebar);
    //window.open("/search/?q=label:" + valOutput, "_self");
    alert(valOutput);
     }
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if(e.style.display == "block") {
                e.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                e.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

`alert()` added to show output.